# Last Updated row ID in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Currently I am working with a project . I required to find last updated id.How can I get last updated row ID in mysql ? Any one help please ?

Comment: put a field column date that generally figure out if the data is updated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a new `AUTO_INCREMENT` value has been generated, you can also obtain it by executing a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` statement with `mysql_query()` and retrieving the value from the result set returned by the statement.

For `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client. It is not even changed if you update another `AUTO_INCREMENT` column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0). Using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed.

[Read more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).

Answer (score 2):

First, edit your table so that it will automatically keep track of whenever a row is modified. Remove the last line if you only want to know when a row was initially inserted.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD lastmodified TIMESTAMP 
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Then, to find out the last updated row, you can use this code.

```
SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 1;
```